# 500 Internal Server Error: Python 3.5, Django and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Python/Django application on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) and getting the following error:

**apache error.log**

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060] mod_wsgi (pid=17060): Target WSGI script '/var/www/demo-app/src/demo/demo/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060] mod_wsgi (pid=17060): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/demo-app/src/demo/demo/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060]   File "/var/www/demo-app/src/demo/demo/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060] mod_wsgi (pid=17060): Target WSGI script '/var/www/demo-app/src/demo/demo/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060] mod_wsgi (pid=17060): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/demo-app/src/demo/demo/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060]   File "/var/www/demo-app/src/demo/demo/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] [pid 17060] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

My setup is as follows:

```
Ubuntu==16.04
django==1.11.4
apache==2.4.18
mod-wsgi==4.5.22
python 3.5(virtualenv)
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

My Apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        WSGIDaemonProcess demo-app python-path=/var/www/demo-app/src/demo:/var/www/demo-app/demoenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup demo-app
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/demo-app/src/demo/demo/wsgi.py
        ...
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: it clearly shows that the application cannot access django, either your virtualenv is not running or you havent installed django inside the virtualenv

Comment: You need to show your Apache/mod_wsgi configuration else can only guess as to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using python in a virtualenv, there are a few things that you might have done wrong.  Two off the top of my head:

- Did you install django while running the virtualenv, so that it installs in that virtualenv's site-packages
- Did you point your apache config to the right Python, something like the following:

> WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/your/wsgi.py
>
> WSGIPythonPath /path/to/your/django/app:/path/to/.virtualenvs/yourvirtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: Please don't recommend use of ``WSGIPythonPath`` or ``python-path`` option of ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` as way to specify location of a virtual environment. That is not the recommended way. For more details see http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had misconfigured my Apache Config file. I changed it 
FROM:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess demo-app python-path=/var/www/demo-app/src/demo:/var/www/demo-app/demoenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

TO:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess demo-app python-path=/var/www/demo-app/src/demo python-home=/var/www/demo-app/demoenv
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have not installed requirements and if you have installed requirements then you may not activated environment where you have installed requirements.

Just activate environment and issue will be resolved.